# Windows in-built RDP client can't disable revocation check?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, certificate, certificate-authority

The server is a Linux PC running XRDP. It is in my home network. I am the only user. I had created a CA and added it to Windows' "Location Computer/Trusted CA". In XRDP.ini, I have set the certificates I created.

The problem is that if I use Windows RDP client, it says that revocation failed and asks me if I want to continue. There is no "Don't ask again."

I have searched the web and found [an answer about actually creating revocation list](https://serverfault.com/questions/378942/how-to-publish-a-crl-for-an-internal-windows-certification-authority), but that seems to be about a real server used by multiple users. In my case, I am the only user, and I know I will not revoke any certificate. In this case, is creating revocation list the only way? Can't I just disable revocation check in Windows' RDP client?

[image]

Comment: Is the CRL distribution point resolvable and reachable from the machine? Provide the CRL Distribution Points entry for the certificate by editing your question. Could you also provide the output of `Certutil -verify -urlfetch <Certificate Filename>` If it's an internal server, then the certificate in question, must be installed on that server also.